# Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (10): x, fill in r shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

In R below code is working but inside r shiny it is giving error.

code :

```
ggplot(df_score) + 
        geom_bar(aes(x=emotion, y=..count.., fill=hashTag),position = "dodge")
```

data :

```
   score hashTag
1  Neutral   hash1
2  Neutral   hash1
3 Positive   hash1
4  Neutral   hash1
5  Neutral   hash1
6 Negative   hash2
```

error :

```
Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (10): x, fill
```

Thanks...

Comment: Unless I am missing something here, your code should be `aes(x=score..` , since there is no variable called `emotion` in your sample dataframe. Also, since the `ggplot2` code is working fine and you are having problems with `shiny` part of the code, you should include that in your question.

Comment: Thanks..I have done a very bad mistake..

Answer (score 1):

You've to add 'Print' in your code.

For example:

```
Graph<-ggplot(df_score) + 
       geom_bar(aes(x=emotion, y=..count.., fill=hashTag),position = "dodge")

print(Graph)
```